# Easiest way to get Zip Code from City Name

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wanted to mess around with an assignment of mine and search for weather by city name rather than by zip code(how i have it set up now). What would be the easiest way to use a city name input string and get a zip code out of it? Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There is an jQuery-plugin for that https://github.com/Loceo/loceo-jquery-plugin

Comment: What makes you think there's a 1-to-1 mapping between city and zip code?  Large cities can encompass dozens of zip codes, and often the weather is very different in different parts of the city.

Answer (score 15):

Google can help you out here!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

The zip is actually called "postal_code" by Google.

```
  "long_name": "94043",
  "short_name": "94043",
  "types": postal_code
```

For example, let's say you want to get the zip for Clarkston, MI...

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Clarkston+MI&sensor=true

This returns:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Clarkston",
               "short_name" : "Clarkston",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Oakland",
               "short_name" : "Oakland",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Michigan",
               "short_name" : "MI",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "48346",
               "short_name" : "48346",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Clarkston, MI 48346, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.7418310,
                  "lng" : -83.41402409999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.7252370,
                  "lng" : -83.42880730000002
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 42.73511960,
               "lng" : -83.41929410
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.74331460,
                  "lng" : -83.40328670
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.72692350,
                  "lng" : -83.43530149999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

## EDIT

If you're not receiving a postal code with that first call, you'll have to make a second call to the same web service using the coordinates from the first call. Still very simple - the call for Stevens Point, WI would be as follows:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.52357920000001,-89.5745630&sensor=true

You can grab the lat/lng values from "location". Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, well i thought it was great, had it implemented and there are no zip codes for any of my surrounding area's returned: Green Bay wi, Stevens Point wi, wausau wi....

Comment: Interesting. Well I guess you'll have to take one extra step, then. If no postal code is presented on the first run, grab the lat and lng values from "location" and run it through the same web service. See my update.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Please check my more up-to date answer below, where I describe my personal proven method to get the most accurate results from Google Maps API. Tested on a website with over 100 million unique locations.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695125/easiest-way-to-get-zip-code-from-city-name/49517473#answer-49517473

Answer (score 2):

The most popular answer above is incomplete. Please check my more up-to date answer below, where I describe my personal proven method to get the most accurate results from Google Maps API. Tested on a website with over 100 million unique locations.

There are many postcodes in each city.

I've had an issue like this one before when I had to generate over 1 million combinations of links for sitemaps with mixed locations + keywords.

At first, I have tried adding keywords "center", "central" & "centre" to the city name as well as the country and it worked 80% of the time, which was not good enough due to the volume I've had to accomplish.

So I kept digging for a better solution and eventually, I have found 2 NEW parameters for Google Maps Geocode API, simply by copy/pasting parts of the results in the query URL.

Please note: This is not documented by Google and whilst it is working just now, it might not work in the future.

***1st Parameter:***

```
&components=country:UK // where "UK" is a country of choice, by utilising this method, rather than adding the Country to the City name, you will avoid clashes and reduce the risk of not getting the postcode.
```

***2nd Parameter:***

```
&location_type=GEOMETRIC_CENTER& // as is, this will get you a place closest to the central geometrical location of the town/city.
```

***Full Example:***

```
var city_name = 'Edinburgh'; // City/Town/Place Name
var country_code = 'GB'; // Great Britain 
var key = 'AIzaSyBk********************cM' // Google API Key

var query = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+city_name+'&components=country:'+country_code+'&location_type=GEOMETRIC_CENTER&key='+key+'&sensor=false
```

Also when looping through JSON sometimes POSTCODE is not in the 1st hierarchy of results, so be sure to loop through the 2nd row, if the 1st one is missing the POSTCODE.

Here is a looping example through the array:

```
url = geocode_query;

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
   result = JSON.parse(out);
   postcode = get_postcode(result); // HERE is Your Postcode do what you need with it
})
.catch(err => { throw err });

function get_postcode(results){ 

    city_data = results['results'][0]['address_components'];
    for(i=0;i<city_data.length;i++){
        var cv = city_data[i];
        if(typeof cv['types'][0] != 'undefined')){
            if(cv['types'][0] === 'postal_code'){
                city['postcode'] = cv['long_name'];
            }else if(cv['types'][0] === 'postal_town'){
                city['place_name'] = cv['postal_town'];
            }
        }
    }

    if(typeof city == 'undefined'){
        city_data = results['results'][1]['address_components'];
        for(i=0;i<city_data.length;i++){
            var cv = city_data[i];
            if(typeof cv['types'][0] != 'undefined')){
                if(cv['types'][0] === 'postal_code'){
                    city['postcode'] = cv['long_name'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return city;

}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing it is by making two calls.

```
    On the first call my query is: geocode('address=' .$cty. ',' .$st, $key);
    $cty = city name - $st = state abbreviation - $key is my api key
    -
    On the second call my query is: geocode('latlng=' .$lat. "," .$lng, $key);
    $lat = latitude from first call - $lng = longitude from first call

---------
My function appears below.
--------------------------------------   
    function geocode($query, $key){
        global $lat, $lng, $zipcode, $city, $state;
        $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'.$query.'&key='.$key;
        $json_string = curlfun($url); // this uses CURL to access the url (false on fail)
        if($json_string){
            $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
        //  
            if ($parsed_json['status'] == "OK"){
                $lat = $parsed_json['results'] [0] ['geometry'] ['location'] ['lat'];
                $lng = $parsed_json['results'] [0] ['geometry'] ['location'] ['lng'];
                foreach($parsed_json['results'] [0] ['address_components'] as $a){
                    if($a ['types'] [0] == 'postal_code') $zipcode = $a ['long_name'];
                    if($a ['types'] [0] == 'locality') $city = $a ['long_name'];
                    if($a ['types'] [0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') $state = $a ['short_name'];   
                    }
                }
            else return false;
            }
        else return false;
        if(!$city) return false; // if there is no city just return false.
    return true;
        }
    ---------------------------------------------------
```

The global variables are available to the rest of the script after the function call.  The function returns false on failure or true on success.  Appropriate error handling should be done in the main code.

Comment: What is curlfun? I don't see a delcaration for that function.

Comment: The code is just a snippet of a larger program that shows the function for querying the api.  curlfun() is a function that uses PHP cURL to return the data from the supplied url.

Answer (score -2):

```
var res; // store response in res variable
var add_array  = res[0].address_components; //add_array = {
               "long_name" : "Clarkston",
               "short_name" : "Clarkston",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Oakland",
               "short_name" : "Oakland",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Michigan",
               "short_name" : "MI",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "48346",
               "short_name" : "48346",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
    var add_array = add_array[add_array.length-1]; //add_array = {
                   "long_name" : "48346",
                   "short_name" : "48346",
                   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                }
    var zip = add_array.long_name;  //zip = 48346
```