# Python - check if given zip code (or city) is in Czech Republic

Tags: python, location

I am to do some address verifications on our company database and problem is that there is another 97 or so countries apart from Czech Republic. They are quite a minority and there is no need to verificate them. Still I need to somehow set them apart, because the API I am currently using for verification can send me only response that it wasn't found.

So I am looking for some tool to recognise Czech ZIP code, or city, etc. In python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer myself.

I can distinguish from what state selected address is thanks to geopy library.

**Input:**

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
location = geolocation.geocode('city-name')
print(location.address)
```

**output (in case city-name == Brno):**

```
Brno, okres Brno-město, Jihomoravský kraj, Jihovýchod, Česko
```

Also I found out, that you can insert another coutry city names in your language and it will find it anyway and that is quite handy.

**output (in case city-name == Mníchov):**

```
München, Bayern, Deutschland
```

Answer (score 3):

The regex that zip code in Czech Republic have is `[0-9]{3} [0-9]{2}|[0-9]{5}`

you can simply check with `re module`

```
import re
regex = r"[0-9]{3} [0-9]{2}|[0-9]{5}"
if re.match(zipcode, regex):
    print("match")
else:
    print("not a match")
```

you can also use `pgeocode` :
https://pypi.org/project/pgeocode/

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But this does not help, it is nice way to check for right format, but lot of other states have it the same way, so you can't really disguinsh what is Czech postal code and what isn't this way. :/

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx and construct a pattern that matches Czest Republic zip codes.

According to wikipedie Czest Republic zip codes are as follows:
`<3 numbers><space><2 numbers>`

Adding to [Tal Folkman anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70531277/14643807) you should also add \b to ensure word boundary.

```py
import re

zip_codes = [
    "123 4",
    "123 45",
    "123 456",
    "1234",
    "12345",
    "123456"
]

for zip_code in zip_codes:
    match = re.match(pattern=r"(\b[\d]{3}[\s][\d]{2}\b|\b[\d]{5}\b)", string=zip_code)
    if match:
        print(f"Match for {zip_code}. Match result: {match.group()}.")
    else:
        print(f"No match for {zip_code}.")
```

Output:

```sh
No match for 123 4.
Match for 123 45. Match result: 123 45.
No match for 123 456.
No match for 1234.
Match for 12345. Match result: 12345.
No match for 123456.
```

**Edit**
Use this handy website https://regex101.com/ to help you build regex patterns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But this does not help, it is nice way to check for right format, but lot of other states have it the same way, so you can't really disguinsh what is Czech postal code and what isn't this way. :/

Comment: Ok, that's probably be difficult. Can you retrieve the country code or name?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695125/easiest-way-to-get-zip-code-from-city-name

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I found that there si a library geopy, that just by passing name of the town, It will give me back response I need, with quite lot of additional information too.